# After print function not able to click other tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using a default print function for printing, but once print function is completed i am not able to click other tabs. Print window is opening in the same page

```
function printReport() {
    var divElements = $('.nicEdit-main').html();
    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + divElements + "</body>";
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens after `window.print();`?  You're not able to click "other tabs" - is that because the previous content on the page doesn't appear, or because it appears but isn't doesn't respond to a click?

Comment: if i close the print window or i click the print option ,then print window will close and will show my page,but after that in my page i am not able to click any tabs ,or buttons etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you just replaced the entire body of your page. `innerHTML` only returns a string form of the HTML *minus the handlers and any data* attached to the elements. Setting the `innerHTML` recreates the DOM from that string *without the handlers* that were originally attached. You just "effectively" paralyzed the page!

I suggest:

- The hard way would be to continue what you are doing, but delegate all handlers to `document` like how `live` would have done it so that they won't be removed. Hard, possible, but not scalable, maintainable or optimal.
- Or you could just create a hidden `iframe` and place your content to be printed there. Then call `print` from that iframe `window` instead. That way, you won't lose your current page.
- Others would create a new window, put content there, run print and close it immediately after. Works the same as iframes, but you wouldn't want a creepy window that opens and closes immediately like some pop-up ad.

Comment: hi thank u,i tried with other function it is working now ,function printReport() {
 var divElements = $('.c3 .nicEdit-main').html();
 var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=500');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divElements + '</html>');
    popupWin.document.close(); 
}

Answer (score 3):

you are loosing the events management. you should hide and show the content you want to print. later, you can redisplay the original and hide the printed.

you can use media queries to change the style of your page when it's printed.

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */
   .nicEdit-main {
      display: block !important;
      width:100%;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't replace the html of the whole page, because that would delete all click handlers (the ones that handle tabs for example)

To print you should do the following:

1. Create a div that is displayed above everything (fixed, height/width: 100%, top/left: 0)
2. Hide everything in body
3. Add the content to be printed to the div
4. Call print
5. Delete the div
6. Restore body state

Something like:

JS

```
function printReport() {
    var $printerDiv = $('<div class="printContainer"></div>'); // create the div that will contain the stuff to be printed
    $printerDiv.html(divElements); // add the content to be printed
    $('body').append($printerDiv).addClass("printingContent"); // add the div to body, and make the body aware of printing (we apply a set of css styles to the body to hide its contents)

    window.print(); // call print
    $printerDiv.remove(); // remove the div
    $('body').removeClass("printingContent");
}
```

CSS

```
body.printingContent > *{
    display: none !important; /* hide everything in body when in print mode*/
}

.printContainer {
    display: block !important; /* Override the rule above to only show the printables*/
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```